# How do I remove a driver when apt-get remove fails?

Tags: debian, dpkg, fglrx

I am trying to remove `fglrx-driver` as part of an upgrade from `wheezy` to `jessie`. Running `apt-get dist-upgrade` failed with the following message:

> ```
> fglrx-driver ...
> dpkg: error processing fglrx-driver (--remove):
>  subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 20
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>  fglrx-driver
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
> ```

I tried running `sudo apt-get remove fglrx*` but got the same message. How do I get around this? Do I need to somehow "unload" the driver? If so, how?

Comment: use modprobe to unload the driver. or rmmod.

Comment: Have you tried `dpkg -r fglrx-driver`?

Comment: @ryekayo yeah, same outcome.

Comment: @mikeserv `FATAL: Module fglrx is in use.`

Comment: @mikeserv I tried booting in recovery mode and running apt-get remove again but I'm getting the same outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleted `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, restarted in recovery mode and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of handling this is to check what is going wrong with the post-removal script and edit as necessary. Note that you can run the post-removal script independently. This is a shell script, lives in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`, and has the suffic `.postrm`. I think apt/dpkg sometimes eat the error messages, so you don't get to see them.

Answer (score 1):

you have to delete xorg and the files from fglrx on xorg.d